# Java instance variable

Tags: java, instance, variable-assignment

I have this question

(i) identify a suitable class for the following items:
Newsweek, Reader's Digest, The Economist, National Geography

(ii) give an example of an instance for the class Hospital

so the first part i am thinking is like this

```
class Magazine{ }
```

The second part what might that be?
can it be like this?

```
Hospital worldgeneralhospital = new Hospital();
```

Comment: Hi JackyBoi, Stackoverflow is not a homework solver.

Comment: Tks man but i am asking for a check on my homework, not a straight answer.. hope you can appreciate me for that atleast..

Comment: @irrelephant hey tks man.. for the check..

Comment: sorry, let me rephrase - Stackoverflow is not a homework checker

Comment: @BinyaminSharet then y is there a home-work tag allowed in the first place?

Comment: I think is a fair question. Maybe the second question is something like princetonPlainsboro = new Hospital();

Comment: @BinyaminSharet would like to divert your attention to this.. and i think in general all the stackoverflow rules are pretty much aligned http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework and according to the post and many people who support the answer (with 55 ups) that a nudge is fine.. pls read the faq..

Comment: @Averroes hey man so u r saying i dont need to mention Hospital princetonPlainsboro = new Hospital(); ?

Comment: @JackyBoi - there's such tag as to let people know when a question is a homework, but there are different levels of questions, and as appears in the FAQ "Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. " not every programming related question fits the site IMHO.

Comment: @JackyBoi No, sorry for the mistake. I was just saying that you need an specific hospital for creating a instance of class Hospital. So the whole sentence would be Hospital princetonPlainsboro = new Hospital();

Comment: @BinyaminSharet and what exactly made you think i am not a enthusiactic programmer? if i am not a 'enthusiactic' programmer then i wouldnot even be asking a question and taking up a programming course.. you can see my other questions and you will know if i am an 'enthsiastic' programmer or not.! 'not every programming related question fits the site..' what exactly doesnot fit in this question, i give u a programming question and then I provide my own answer and then I ask u its correct or not. Then u quickly say stackovrflow doesnot entertain 'my kind' of questions.. pls dont be quick 2 judge

Comment: @Averroes yes man thats what i tot so too.. tks

Comment: This is good - in the first part you are identifying some common element to all those objects, and in the second you are creating a new instance of a specific class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `new MyClass()` creates instance of `MyClass`.

Comment: hey tks but i am trying to have the ii) of the question entered in the next line how to do that?